# RushORM get created and updated time

Tags: android, database, sqlite, rushorm

Currently I'm trying [RushORM](http://www.rushorm.com/) in an Android Application but I've no idea how to access the created and updated fields in the database. 
The fields rush_created and rush_updated are created automatically and get filled as expected.

But again I've no idea how to access these files. 
Even when serializing the DB objects the fields are missing.

So does anyone know how to access them?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked the developer:

> RushCore.getInstance().getMetaData(yourObject).getCreated(); 
>   It returns updated and created as a long so you will just have to create
>   a new Date with the value.

If anyone needs those values too.